# Can comments be used in a Valgrind suppression file?

Tags: valgrind

## How do I put a comment in a Valgrind suppression file?

I need to maintain a Valgrind suppression file for a large project. We filter unfixable errors from a tool we link to. It's likely that this file will need to be updated over time as new releases of the tool are released.

Here is an example of a rule we're suppressing:

```
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Cond
   fun:Wredxor
   obj:/tmp/*/vcs_sim_exe*
   ...
   fun:SNPSle_*
   ...
   fun:VCS_MAIN
   obj:/tmp/*/vcs_sim_exe*
   ...
   fun:main
}
```

I'd like to add *something like* the following line before (or inside the rule):

`// Rule added for release 2019.X.Y.Z release.`

I have not been able to find a reference to comments in the [Valgrind documentation](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.suppfiles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments in a suppression file are starting with a # character.
https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress
should mention that (and will soon :)).

Comment: I have added "Blank and comment lines in a suppression file are ignored. Comment lines are made of 0 or more blanks followed by a # character followed by some text." in the user manual.  Will be in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend that you use something unique and explanatory for the `<insert_a_suppression_name_here>` string. In particular if you want to use the suppression file with a test suite, this will allow you to track which suppressions are being used (via either the -v or -s options).